# Sub-menu vertically align

Tags: html, css, alignment

I've got a simple menu that should show a sub-menu vertically. However, i changed this menu to be in order to center it, and it now doesn't show vertically but horizontally.

Here is my codepen :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGwmGq

```
    .navitem{
height: 30px;
}

#menu ul {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 list-style-type:none;
 text-align:center;
 }
#menu li {

 background-color:black;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
 }
#menu li a {
 display:block;
 width:125px;
 color:white;
 text-decoration:none;
 line-height:30px

 }
#menu li a:hover {
 color:#FFD700;
 }

#menu ul li ul {
 display:none;
 }

 #menu ul li:hover ul {
 display:block;
 }

#menu li:hover ul li {
 float:none;


 }

#menu li ul {
 position:absolute;
 } 

#menu {
 height:30px;
 margin-top: 30px;

 } 

.table {
    display: table;   /* Allow the centering to work */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
/* Logo */ 
#logo{
 height: 190px;
 width: 266px;
  background-color:black;
  margin: 0 30px;
}
/* Fin MENU */
```

As you can see, the "portfolio" actually shows the sub-menu but this sub-menu should be vertically aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For li you have given display as inline-block that,s why they are coming in one line. so for portfolio submenu Write this css in your css file

```
#menu ul li ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have deleted the positioning context on the `li`

```
#menu li {
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative; /* add this */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Add `display:block` to your sub menu `li`.

```
#menu li:hover ul li {
 float:none;
 display:block; /* Add This */
 }
```

**UPDATED : EXPLANATION**

1) `display:block;` property is a block property in HTML. So every element with such property takes a new line(Elements views Vertically).

2) `display:inline-block;` property is a block but **inline** property. So elements which such property appears on same single line(Elements views Horizontally).

[Working : Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/nduz6vc3/1/)

Answer (score 1):

In your css, you're making all main menu items inline using `#menu li` selector, which is also applied for `li`s in sub menu.

So you've to explicitly specify `display: block` for sub menu `li`s

Change your code as given below.

```
#menu li:hover ul li {
   float:none;
   display:block;
 }
```